# How to create message queue in HAL Management Console?

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I faced the following problem: I need to create a messaging queue in HAL Management Console. In the video tutorial, it looks like this: [image]

But in tutorial author uses an old version of the console as I understand. I have a bit another menu which doesn't have a messaging menu item. I found mail menu item:[image]

But as I understand, this is not what I need as I didn't find any way to create the queue here. Maybe someone knows how to create a messaging queue? I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've not used the console as it is difficult to script for the *next* time you need to do this again.  Instead, I've used the CLI to do this.

To create the topic:

```
${wildfly.home}/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=127.0.0.1:8080 --command="jms-topic add --topic-address=yourTopicName --entries=java:/jms/yourTopicName"
```

where `wildfly.home` is the directory where Wildfly is installed.  To remove a JMS queue, you'll run something like:

```
${wildfly.home}/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=127.0.0.1:8080 --command="jms-topic remove --topic-address=yourTopicName"
```

My producer code looks like:

```
@Stateless
public class MyProducer {
    @Resource(lookup = "java:/jms/yourTopicName")
    private Topic topic;

    @Inject
    private JMSContext context;

    public void sendMessage(MyCustomMessage customMessage) {
        try {
            ObjectMessage message = context.createObjectMessage();
            message.setObject(customMessage);
            context.createProducer().send(topic, message);
        }
        catch (JMSException e) {
            // handle error
        }
    }
}
```

and my listener looks like:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "java:/jms/yourTopicName"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic") })
public class MyListener implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
    }
}
```

Remember that to use JMS you need to run with the "full" configuration, i.e.

`bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml`

Answer (score 1):

You probably had started Wildfly in the default mode (> without the JMS broker !).
If you want to see the Messaging menu in the console, you need to use the alternate configuration named `standalone-full`.

In a terminal session, go into the "bin" folder of Wildfy, and then type:

```
./standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-full.xml
```

(or standalone.bat for Windows)

More info [here](https://docs.wildfly.org/17/Getting_Started_Guide.html#wildfly-10-configurations)